# How can I invite a user to a newly created private chat channel using the Twilio Python Client?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

How can I invite a user to a newly created private chat channel using the Twilio Python Client?

The python channel instance does not have an `channel.invite()` method like the JS SDK does.

I have looked through the source code as well but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Programmable Chat REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest) actually has an [Invites resource that you can use to invite users to channels](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/invites). You can use it like this:

```
channel.invites.create(user_identity)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.